# Rails seeds.db not saving relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to use the db/seeds.rb file to prepopulate the database, my code looks like:

```
 now = Time.now.beginning_of_hour
later = Time.now.end_of_hour + 1
sch1 = Schedule.create(start_time: now, stop_time: later) 
sch1.channel = channel
sch1.program = cartoon
cartoon.schedules.push(sch1)
sch1.save
cartoon.save
```

where channel and cartoon are defined earlier in the code with a Channel.create and Program.create with appropriate values.

When I look in the rails console, I see that all three objects (channel, program and schedule) exist, but that no schedule has no program_id.  (schedule.program works just fine for some reason).  A program's program.schedules is an empty array as well.

As a test, I did the following in the console:

```
now = Time.now.beginning_of_hour
later = Time.now.end_of_hour + 1
channel = Channel.first
cartoon = Program.first
sch1 = Schedule.create(start_time: now, stop_time: later) 
sch1.channel = channel
sch1.program = cartoon
cartoon.schedules.push(sch1)
sch1.save
cartoon.save
```

and that worked just fine.

What is special about seeds?  Do I need to call save before referencing it later or something?  the variable is clearly not null...

Comment: Did you just missed to include `channel = Channel.first
cartoon = Program.first ` when you copied from seeds.rb or it isn`t there?

Comment: No, "channel and cartoon are defined earlier in the code with a Channel.create and Program.create with appropriate values." in the seeds, while in the rails console I just grab the already created values.